# Z-index bug in IE6/IE7

Tags: css

Take a look at the following website: http://driz.co.uk/mars/index.html

If you look at the jQuery slider thingy at the bottom right in IE6/IE7 you will notice that the orange arrows appear behind the white gradient overlays even though the z-index of the arrows is set to higher values than that of the overlays.

It works fine in all the other browsers I've tested it on, including IE8 just 7 and 6 display the indexing wrong. Any ideas? Need to get this project out asap. Thanks.

Comment: From what I've noticed looking around in your code, you seem to have set z-index only on the arrow divs and not on the photo-slider. Try doing that.

Comment: I have the index on the overlay and also the arrows so the arrows should appear above the overlay (which they in IE8, Chrome, etc)

Comment: I added the z-index to the slider and it breaks it in ALL browsers now...

Answer (score 1):

This is a documented bug with IE6. Quarksmode.org has a article on it.
http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html

The above article does not contain a workaround but in the comments a fellow mentioned that giving the parent element a higher z-index actual fixes the bug. Don’t ask me why this works but it does!

```
<div style="z-index: 3000">
    <div style="position:absolute;z-index:1000;">
        <a href="#">Page</a>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<img style="position:absolute" src="myimage.png" />
```